# None-unique column index error using cur.fetch_pandas_all() to extract data from Snowflake

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm pulling results from Snowflake using the code below.  The SQL statement returns fine in Snowflake Web UI but when pulled in Python I get a **ValueError: Found non-unique column index**

If this happened in my Pandas workflow, I would reset_index() but, as its happening at the point of the dataframe being created I'm unsure how to fix this.

As an interim, I'm exporting a csv from Snowflake and importing into Python which I hate doing as I'm refreshing multiple times a week.

```
cur.execute(sql)
df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered, that although snowflake allows the return of identical named columns in the webui, this is not compatible with pandas.

Just renaming in the SQL statement as below resolved the issue.

> Select XXX as XXX_2

Comment: I will also mention that selecting specific columns can help (if your query is selecting all with several joins).

Answer (score 0):

Have just tried forming the df like this and it worked.

```py
cur.execute(sql)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this works because it doesn't look at the column names, so duplicate names do not raise an exception (see Mark Heptonstall's answer). This is an alternative solution, if you don't know which column names are duplicated and you don't need the column names.